# Paypal API - is it possible to transfer amount directly between users

Tags: paypal

I have configured Paypal API on my site.I can receive payment's from users to my site.

Is it possible to transfer amount from one user's PayPal account to another user's PayPal account directly or if I know PayPal email address  two users can I transfer amount between them is there any API for this.

Comment: You can transfer your own money wherever you like. You can't transfer anybody else's. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: there is an option for future payment where we can have the user to give our app the permission to send money on their behalf ,but as far as my knowledge we can send that to our site only not to another user is that correct